# Deserialize JSON with Nancy

Tags: json, nancy

I want to deserialize JSON from `POST` request. I know about binding to models, but what if I have a local variable, and JSON only contains one property.

For example how can I get this:

```
{
    "ID": "07149915-5c76-46c5-9c2f-2bb86ee203f2"
}
```

And pass it to something like this:

```
var someIdName = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it to a dynamic like this

```
var model = this.Bind<dynamic>();
```

then you can access your data like `model.ID`